# Ant-design Modal not closing when passing prop to control it

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

I have the following Modal (TestModal) in a separate component:

```
<Modal
    title="title"
    centered={true}
    visible={this.props.isOpen}
    okText="Close"
    onOk={this.props.onClose}
>
    Test
</Modal>
```

Then within another component I have this:

```
class ModalContainer extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isModalOpen: false,
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={() => this.setState({ isModalOpen: true })}>
                <TestModal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} onClose={() => this.setState({ isModalOpen: false })} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now when I click the container the isOpen prop changes to true and its passed into the Modal which then shows it. Now when I click the isOk button it should close the modal (isModalOpen = false) However nothing happens. When I console.log the value of isModalOpen when I click the "close" button it keeps showing true. For some reason it does not change to false.

Any idea if its a react issue or antd issue?

React: 16.13.1
antd: 4.1.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is happening because of the `onClick` handler present in `div` on `ModalContainer`. When the close button is clicked on `Modal` the click event bubbles to the `div` click handler as well which sets the state to `true` again.

The solution for this is to stop the bubbling of click event. You can try doing this:

```
 <TestModal
     isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}
     onClose={e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.setState({ isModalOpen: false });
     }}
/>
```

Here is the same solution implemented in CodeSandbox. Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-bohr-637jo?file=/src/App.js:402-589

Answer (score -2):

this worked for me  `onCancel={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); setIsModalOpen1(false); }}`

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.